# How to declare an object's logger in logger.xml?

Tags: scala, playframework, logback

I need finer grained control of my logging in my Play 2.1 application.  To this end, I have been putting a unique logger in each Controller like follows:

```
package controllers.admin
object Accounts extends Controller {
  val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass())

  def session = Action { implicit request =>
    log.trace("session {}", request)
    val body: AnyContent = request.body
    log.debug("body: {}", body);
    val jsonBody: Option[JsValue] = body.asJson
    Ok("Hello " + jsonBody)
  }
}
```

The problem this creates is in the conf/logger.xml file.  When I use the object's proper name; controllers.admin.Accounts$ in this case, the play runtime spews stacktrace on me.

```
09:08:05,885 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@24:62 - RuntimeException in Action for tag [logger] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse input [controllers.admin.Accounts$]
    at java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse input [controllers.admin.Accounts$]
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.substVars(OptionHelper.java:125)
...
```

My conf/logger.xml looks like

```
<logger name="play" level="info" />
<logger name="application" level="debug" />
<logger name="controllers.admin.Accounts$" level="trace" />
```

I'm guessing it hates the '$', but thats what Scala does with the getClass name of "object" types.  What can I do in logger.xml to correctly declare this logger?  Alternatively, what can I do in the Play Controller declarations to avoid the whole '$' problem without introducing cut-and-paste errors and the like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try a simple trait to handle removal of the $ when creating the logger like this:

```
trait ControllerLogging{
  lazy val log = {
    val className = getClass().getName match{
      case x if x.endsWith("$") => x.substring(0, x.length() - 1)
      case x => x
    }
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(className)
  }
}
```

Then mix into your controller:

```
object Accounts extends Controller with ControllerLogging
```

Comment: That looks promising.  I'll give it a whirl.